# Diagram of the subgroups of $D_4=\langle a,b:a^4=1,b^2=1,ba=a^3b \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried to make the diagram of the subgroups of $D_4=\langle a,b:a^4=1,b^2=1,ba=a^3b \rangle$

[image]

although,in my notes there is this one:

[image]

Which of them is right?

**EDIT:**

To find all the subgroups of $D_4$ I did the following:
$$<1>=\{1\}$$
$$<a>=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}=<a^3>$$
$$<b>=\{1,b\}$$
$$<a^2b>=\{1,a^2b\}$$
$$<a^3b>=\{1,a^3b\}$$
$$<ab>=\{1,ab\}$$
$$<a^2>=\{1,a^2\}$$
$$<a,b>=\{1,a,b,ab\} \checkmark $$
$$<a,a^2b>=\{1,a,a^2b,a^3b\} \checkmark $$
$$<a,a^3b>=\{1,a,a^3b,b\} \checkmark$$
$$<a,ab>=\{1,a,ab,a^2b\} \checkmark$$
$$<a,a^2>=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}=<a> \times $$
$$<a,a^3>=\{1,a,a^3 \}, ord=3 \nmid 8 \times$$
$$<b,a^2b>=\{1,b,a^2b,a^2\} \checkmark$$
$$<b,a^3b>=\{1,b,a^3b,a\}=<a,a^3b> \times$$
$$<b,ab>=\{1,b,ab,a^3\} \checkmark$$
$$<b,a^2>=\{1,b,a^2,a^2b\}=<b,a^2b> \times$$
$$<b,a^3>=\{1,b,a^3,ab\}=<b,ab> \times $$
$$<a^2b,a^3b>=\{1,a^2b,a^3b,a^3\} \checkmark$$
$$<a^2b,ab>=\{1,a^2b,ab,a\}=<a,ab> \times$$
$$<a^2b,a^2>=\{1,a^2b,a^2,b\}=<b,a^2b> \times$$
$$<a^2b,a^3>=\{1,a^2b,a^3,a^3b\}=<a^2b,a^3b> \times$$
$$<a^3b,ab>=\{1,a^3b,ab,a^2\} \checkmark$$
$$<a^3b,a^2>=\{1,a^3b,a^2,ab\}=<a^3b,ab> \times$$
$$<a^3b,a^3>=\{1,a^3b,a^3,b\} \checkmark$$
$$<ab,a^2>=\{1,ab,a^2,a^3b\}=<a^3b,ab> \times$$
$$<ab,a^3>=\{1,ab,a^3,a^2b\} \checkmark$$
$$<a^2,a^3>=\{1,a^2,a^3,a\}=<a> \times$$

Therefore:

The subgroups of $D_4$ are the following:

$\text{ ord }=8 :$ $$\ \ \ D_4$$
$\text{ ord }=4 :$ $$ \ \ \ <a>, \ <a,b>, \ <a,a^2b>, \ <a,a^3b>, \ <a,ab>, \ <b,a^2b>, \  <b,ab>, \\ <a^2b,a^3b>,  \ <a^3b,ab>,  \ <a^3b,a^3>,  \ <ab,a^3>$$
$\text{ ord }=2 :$ $$ \ \ \ <b>,  \ <a^2b>,  \ <a^3b>, \  <ab>,  \ <a^2>$$
$\text{ ord }=1 :$ $$ \ \ \ <1>$$

Is it right?

But...at the lattice from my notes there aren't so many subgroups...What have I done wrong?

Comment: Diagram of subgroup (it is actually called as lattice) should contain all subgroups.. where as the one which you have described does not show $\langle a^2,b\rangle$.. So your diagram is ???

Comment: In reference to your suggested diagram : how is $\langle b\rangle$ a subgroup of $\langle a\rangle$? How did you come up with your diagram?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What does $<a^2,b>$ mean?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat How can I check if $<b>$ is a subgroup of $<a>$ ?

Comment: it is subgroup generated by $a^2$ and $b$...

Comment: to check if $\langle b\rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle a^2\rangle$ all you have to do is to see if any power of $a^2$ is $b$... Can you check that?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik A ok.. From the subgroups $\displaystyle{<b>,<a^2>,<ab>,<a^2b>,<a^3b>}$, the only one that is a subgroup of $\displaystyle{<a>}$ is $\displaystyle{<a^2>}$, right?

Comment: To find all the subgroups I did the following:
$$D_4=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b\}$$
$$1^1=1:ord(1)=1$$
$$a^1=a, \dots, a^4=1:ord(a)=4$$
$$b^1=b, b^2=1:ord(b)=2$$
$$(a^2b)^1=a^2b, (a^2b)^2=1:ord(a^2b)=2$$
$$(a^3b)^1=a^3b, (a^3b)^2=1:ord(a^3b)=2$$
$$(a^2)^1=a^2, (a^2)^2=1:ord(a^2)=2$$
$$(a^3)^1=a^3, \dots , (a^3)^3=1:ord(a^3)=3$$
$$(ab)^1=ab, (ab)^2=1:ord(ab)=2$$
But...how can I find for example the subgroup $\displaystyle{<a^2,b>}$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I edited my post...I tried to find all the subgroups of $D_4$. Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I edited my post...I tried to find all the subgroups of $D_4$. Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: @evinda : I do not have to say anything.. you can check yourself if you have all subgroups which are there in original diagram of subgroups... you have more number of subgroups that that are shown in diagram... see that there are some subgroups which are equal.... so you are counting something more than once...

Comment: Not all the "subgroups" that you found actually *are*  subgroups. Many of them are not multiplicatively closed. For example, $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ is not multiplicatively closed, since $a^2$ isn't an element. In point of fact, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is all of $D_4$...by definition!

Answer (score 4):

None of $b,ab,a^2b,$ or $a^3b$ is an element of $\langle a\rangle,$ so your diagram is incorrect. Keep in mind that not all subgroups are necessarily cyclic! However, it's a good idea to start by finding the cyclic subgroups. In particular, you should find that $$\langle 1\rangle =\{1\},$$ $$\langle a\rangle=\langle a^3\rangle=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\},$$ $$\langle a^2\rangle=\{1,a^2\},$$ $$\langle b\rangle=\{1,b\},$$ $$\langle ab\rangle=\{1,ab\},$$ $$\langle a^2b\rangle=\{1,a^2b\},$$ and $$\langle a^3b\rangle=\{1,a^3b\}.$$ Observe that from this, we can conclude that $1$ has order one, $a$ and $a^3$ have order four, and all the other elements of $D_4$ have order two.

Next, we'll want to find all the subgroups generated by *two* elements of $D_4,$ but if we choose two elements that already share a cyclic subgroup, then we won't get anything new--for example, $\langle a,a^2\rangle=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}=\langle a\rangle$--so we'll want to choose two elements that don't already share a cyclic subgroup. For example, let's take $a^2$ and $b.$ Now, since $a^2\in\langle a^2,b\rangle$ by definition, then $\langle a^2\rangle\subseteq\langle a^2,b\rangle.$ (Why?) Likewise, $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a^2b\rangle,$ and so $1,a^2,b\in\langle a^2,b\rangle.$ Also, $a^2b$ will be in there (since otherwise, we wouldn't have multiplicative closure). One can show that $ba^2=a^2b,$ and from this, we can show that $\{1,a^2,b,a^2b\}$ is multiplicatively closed, and so is precisely the subgroup of $D_4$ generated by $a^2$ and $b.$ In fact, $$\langle a^2,b\rangle=\langle a^2,a^2b\rangle=\langle b,a^2b\rangle=\{1,a^2,b,a^2b\},$$ and we can similarly find that $$\langle a^2,ab\rangle=\langle a^2,a^3b\rangle=\langle ab,a^3b\rangle=\{1,a^2,ab,a^3b\}.$$ This takes care of all of our proper subgroups. But how can we see this?

The kicker here is to recall that (1) the order of an element must be a factor of the order of any subgroup in which it lies--so for example, any subgroup of $D_4$ with $a$ as an element must have some multiple of $4$ elements in it, so must either have $4$ elements or be the whole group--and (2) that the order of any subgroup must be a factor of the order of the group--meaning that every subgroup's order must be some factor of $8,$ which is the order of $D_4$. Consequently, the *only* proper subgroup in which $a$ lies is $\langle a\rangle,$ and the same holds for $a^3.$ But to pick two elements of $D_4$ that don't lie in the same cyclic subgroup, at least one of them must be of the form $a^kb$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}.$ We've already taken care of all cases in which the other chosen element is $a^2,$ and we've seen that the other element can't be $a$ or $a^3$ without generating the whole group, so all that's left is to consider the subgroups of the form $\langle a^jb,a^kb\rangle,$ where $j,k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $j<k.$ But in each case, we can show that $a$ or $a^3$ must lie in the subgroup (so we have the whole group), or that $a^2$ lies in the subgroup (so by the earlier work, we see that there are more than $4$ elements in the subgroup, but the only factor of $8$ greater than $4$ is $8,$ and so we again have the whole group).

In general, we might be able to then go on to find proper subgroups generated by three or more elements, which we'd want to choose so that they didn't all lie in one of the previously-determined subgroups. Fortunately, in this case, we didn't have to do that much work.

Comment: A ok..Do you know what $<a^2,b>$ means?

Comment: And also..why is none of $b,ab,a^2b,a^3b$ an element of $<a>$ ?

Comment: $\langle a^2,b\rangle$ indicates the subgroup of $D_4$ generated by $a^2$ and $b$--that is, the smallest subgroup of $D_4$ that has $a^2$ and $b$ as elements. Similarly, $\langle a$ is the smallest subgroup of $D_4$ that has $a$ as an element. A cyclic subgroup is one that can be written as a subgroup generated by a single element--for example, $\langle a,a^2\rangle$ is cyclic, since any subgroup with $a$ as an element *automatically* has $a^2$ as an element, so $\langle a,a^2\rangle=\langle a\rangle.$

Comment: Now, $\langle a\rangle=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}.$ Since $b\notin\langle a\rangle$ then we can see/show that *none* of $b,ab,a^2b,a^3b$ is an element of $\langle a\rangle.$

Comment: As for how we may find which elements are in $\langle a^2,b\rangle,$ we can start by noting that $1,a^2,b$ are elements, and so readily $a^2b$ is an element. But no matter how we multiply $1,a^2,b,a^2b,$ we will not get any other elements (which you should prove). Thus, $\langle a^2,b\rangle=\{1,a^2,b,a^2b\}.$

Comment: To find all the subgroups I did the following:
$$D_4=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab,a^2b,a^3b\}$$
$$1^1=1:ord(1)=1$$
$$a^1=a, \dots ,a^4=1:ord(a)=4$$
$$b^1=b,b^2=1:ord(b)=2$$
$$(a^2b)^1=a^2b,(a^2b)^2=1:ord(a^2b)=2$$
$$(a^3b)^1=a^3b,(a^3b)^2=1:ord(a^3b)=2$$
$$(a^2)^1=a^2,(a^2)^2=1:ord(a^2)=2$$
$$(a^3)^1=a^3, \dots ,(a^3)^3=1:ord(a^3)=3$$
$$(ab)^1=ab,(ab)^2=1:ord(ab)=2$$
So,do I have to take now all the combinations of two elements and check if it's a subgroup of $D_4$?Or is there an other way to find them?

Comment: In this case,it cannot be that in one subgroup there are more than two elements, right? But in other groups, I have to check it,or am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, you've miscalculated the order of $a^3$ (though all the rest are fine). $$(a^3)^3=a^9=a^{4+4+1}=a^4a^4a=1\cdot1\cdot a=a\ne1,$$ so the order of $a^3$ is definitely not $3.$ Keep in mind that an element's order must always be a factor of the size of the group, and $3$ is not a factor of $8.$ Rather, you should find that the order of $a^3$ is $4$. As for finding all the subgroups, you are wrong that no subgroup has more than $2$ elements--as shown in the diagram from your notes, there are actually $4$ subgroups of $D_4$ ($3$ of which are proper) that have more than $2$ elements.

Comment: I will expand my answer to give a general approach you can take when finding all the subgroups of a finite group.

Comment: Oh,yes!!! Sorry!!! Do you mean that one of the $4$ subgroups of $D_4$ that has more than $2$ elements is:
$$<a^2,b>=\{1,a^2,b,a^2b\}$$?
But in this group there is no subgroup in the form:
$$<x,y,z>$$ right?($ x,y,z \in D_4$)

Comment: Ah! I see what you meant, now. It is true that every subgroup of $D_4$ can be generated by at most two elements. However, that doesn't mean we can't still write some of them in the form $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ for some $x,y,z\in D_4.$ For example, $\langle a^2,b,a^2b\rangle$ is still a subgroup (in fact, a proper one!), but we can write it more simply as $\langle a^2,b\rangle.$

Comment: Aa.. Ok! I have edited my post...I tried to find all the subgroups of $D_4$. Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: I eliminated those that are not multiplicatively closed. The remained subgroups of order $4$ are the following:
$\text{ ord }=4 :$ $$ \ \ \ <a>,  \ <b,a^2b>, \  <b,ab>,  \ <a^3b,ab>,  \ <a^3b,a^3>,  \ <ab,a^3>$$

But...there are still more subgroups of order $4$ than at the lattice of my notes... What have I done wrong?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you *still* haven't eliminated them all. This is a very good exercise to familiarize you with determining subgroups generated by finitely-many elements. Looking at your post, I see at least ten subgroups $\langle x,y\rangle$ that you have incorrectly determined (I stopped counting at ten). I highly recommend that, rather than eliminating those that are not multiplicatively closed, you *fix* them. Keep in mind that for any $x,y\in D_4,$ we have that $\langle x\rangle\cup\langle y\rangle\subseteq\langle x,y\rangle.$ That gives you a good place to start.

Comment: Also, please read my answer carefully. I know it's long, but there is a lot of useful information packed in there. If you have any questions about specific claims I make in my answer, please don't hesitate to ask, once you've given them some thought.

Comment: Incidentally, the diagram from your notes (as posted) is incorrect. For one thing, $\langle ab\rangle$ should be included. For another thing, it shouldn't be $\langle a^3,b\rangle,$ but rather $\langle a^3b,a^2\rangle$ or $\langle a^3b,ab\rangle$ or $\langle a^2,ab\rangle.$ Finally, some of your connecting lines are incorrect or missing. Take a look and see if you can determine which belong and which don't, to generate a truly correct lattice.

Comment: If I get the time later today, I will do what I can to streamline my answer.